# Process Builder Formula Conditions are met

Tags: process-builder, conditional, criteria-filter

Sorry I've been drilling this for 8 hours and I'm stuck...

I *can* get this to work using "Formula Evaluates to to True"

NOT(CONTAINS([User].Email, 'gmail') )

But I can't get it to work using "Conditions are met" using: 
Field*  Operator*   Type*   Value*

I need it to work via "Conditions are met" because I have 15-30 "Conditions"...

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

((Edit, this is a process that changes the users Profile, if active is not checked, & in this particular instance if the users email does not contain (for example) 'gmail'. We don't want those users to change profiles upon deactivation.

**Edit**

In a formula, how would I link these together?

NOT(CONTAINS([User].Email, 'gmail') )

NOT(CONTAINS([User].Email, 'hotmail') )

NOT(CONTAINS([User].Email, 'yahoo') )

NOT(CONTAINS([User].Email, 'outlook') )

NOT(CONTAINS([User].Email, 'aol') )

NOT(CONTAINS([User].Email, 'example') )

I did find a sort of loophole in all of that and that's, in the initial criteria, I can use the "Conditions are met" & in the Immediate Action, it gives me a 2nd chance to set another criteria in which case I can use a formula there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the formula `NOT(CONTAINS())` is a Boolean value - either `true` or `false`. The content of the User's email field will never equal that value.

You need to define your criteria using the Operator drop-down:

[image]

To combine multiple criteria and negate them, use filter logic:

[image]

You *can* use formulas, but don't think of it as checking whether the formula is true for a field value - think of the formula as calculating something you want to compare the field value against. Most of the time you won't use formulas with your operator-based criteria.

Comment: So I can't use contains because we only want the Immediate Action to work if the email address 'Does Not Contain' "gmail.com". We're doing it this way so that internal email addresses do not trigger the action but all other email addresses will. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi David, I edited the post up there, could you provide insight please?

Comment: This is awesome David thank you! I dug through so many forums trying to find a solution and NOT (1 OR 2) was right in front of me. This is perfect, I can't thank you enough.